# Dynamically creating XElements inside XDocument using a loop

Tags: c#, html, foreach, linq-to-xml, xelement

I need to be able to dynamically create 'n' number of XElements inside an XDocument using a loop and depending on the number of files found within a directory.

My WIP bare bones project code is possibly slightly long to paste here so I have added it to pastie.org - [here](http://pastie.org/private/qfjfrg5tfia6fjeu4e3dcq#3)

You will see that between lines 73-91 that I have a foreach loop that searches through a directory & it's sub-directories and locates the paths of all the files contained within.
I know that this on it's own works as I have used:

`int x = filePaths.Length;`

and the output of `x` matches the number of files in the given directory.

The main bulk of the code also works and creates a HTML file as I require but I also need it to dynamically create 'n' XElements between line 215 where I have placed:

`///  **** NEED TO INSERT LOOP HERE TO DYNAMICALLY CREATE NUMBER OF ELEMENTS DEPENDING ON NUMBER OF FILES IN DIRECTORY ****`

just before the opening of a `<TR>` tag & line 280, just after the closing of a `<TR>` tag so each file found within the specified directory will have it's own `<TABLE>` row.

I have lost count as to the number of ways I have tried to achieve this by moving the loop around throughout the code but keep hitting a brick wall with masses of errors.

Initially I thought it would be as simple as to just place the loop in the code at line 215 but doing this causes numerous errors such as missing:

- ;
- }

etc...

Now I am completely stuck.

I am trying to emulate in C# a batch file I made some time ago that uses WMIC that works perfectly well but is limited & I wish to add a few more features, this is where C# comes in.

The batch file uses a loop, just as I am trying to here, without any problems at all.

Here is the loop from the WMIC batch file:

```
(FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /s /n "C:\Users\1CM69\Pics & Vids\Archives\Family\2002"') DO (
FOR /f "tokens=1-3*" %%x IN ('dir /a-d /tc "%%~a"^|findstr "^[0-9]"') DO (
  for /f %%c in ("%%~ta") do (
ECHO ^<TR^>^<td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: inset;border-color: gray;background-color: white;" align="center" valign="middle"^>^<a href="%%a" target="_new"^>^<img src="%%a" width="100px" border="0"^>^</a^>^</TD^>^<td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: inset;border-color: gray;background-color: white;" align="left" valign="middle"^>^<B^>%%~nxa^</B^>^</TD^>^<td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: inset;border-color: gray;background-color: white;" align="center" valign="middle"^>^<B^>%%~c^</B^>^</TD^>^<td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: inset;border-color: gray;background-color: white;" align="center" valign="middle"^>^<B^>%%x^</B^>^</TD^>^</TR^> >> 2002.html))))
```

I found [Create XML with XDocument with a variable number of XElements using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946830/create-xml-with-xdocument-with-a-variable-number-of-xelements-using-for-loop) will searching around & was initially hopeful and although I did get it to dynamically create 'n' number of XElements based on the number of files, the variable `DateTaken` only showed the value of the last file within the directory, so I had a `<TABLE>` with 68 rows `<TR>`, in the case of the test directory I am using, and they all contained the values retrieved from the final file that the loop found.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Regards..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a loop, use a LINQ `from .. select ..` expression e.g.

```
from file in filePaths
select new XElement("tr", 
  new XElement("td",
    new XElement("a", new XAttribute("href", file), new XAttribute("target", "_new"), new XElement("img", new XAttribute("src", file), new XAttribute("width", "100"))),
    new XElement("td", file),
    new XElement("td", GetDate(file))
  ))
```

To extract the date write a method that encapsulates your code e.g.

```
string GetDate(string path) {

try
                                        {

                                        Bitmap MyPhoto = new Bitmap(file);
                                        const int IDDateTimeOriginal = 36867;
                                        PropertyItem TakenDate = MyPhoto.GetPropertyItem(IDDateTimeOriginal);
                                        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
                                        return ascii.GetString(TakenDate.Value, 0, TakenDate.Len - 1);
                                        }


                                        catch //(ArgumentException) if the property doesn't exists
                                        {
                                          return "MISSING ENTRY";
                                        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, initially this seemed a simple a logical answer and did kind of work. It created the correct number of rows based on number of files but again, only the values from the last file in the directory populated every one of the rows in the table. I am a bit lost here...

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of a sample table row that you want to create for a sample file path in your `filePaths` variable? I am afraid the WMIC sample is not something I understand.

Comment: Link to a shortened down version of the outputted `<TABLE>`. I have inc the `<TABLE>` header section to add clarity. I know that my code is yet to deal with the populating of the THUMBNAIL column or the FILENAME column of the `<TABLE>` but retrieving that data from the `filePaths` variable should be a breeze after solving this issue 1st. You can see that the DATE TAKEN column is populated with the DateTimeOriginal field from the particular images EXIF data, this is supposed to be done for all the images inside the directory by iteration. [link](http://pastie.org/private/d3wuh87zpyrqvrfvscdhia)

Comment: Here is the batch file that does exactly what I am trying to achieve in C#.   [LINK](http://pastie.org/private/olmo7ryjk7p6i0z2mhmjq) this may help.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack Overflow and forgot to add commenters name when replying, so: @martin

Comment: @1cm69, I have edited my answer to show how to produce the `tr` elements and populate them. Can you try along those lines? Are you really getting several `tr` elements that way, but all populated with the same data from the last file? I can't  imagine why, unless you do that `XDocument` creation inside the `foreach` over your `filePaths`, you need to make sure you move that code constructing the `XDocument` outside of that `foreach`.

Comment: @ martin thanks. I have edited my code to reflect using the snippet you kindly posted and it does create the correct number of `tr` elements all populated with the correct data apart from the last column, the Date Taken one that is supposed to get the data from the `DateTaken` variable. At the moment all it does is populate the last column of the `table` with the `DateTaken` data from the last file in the directory. It looks like it is disregarding the `foreach` loop somehow. Here is another link to the updated code - [LINK](http://pastie.org/private/gda7bljt6qyiy7hgkq68w)

Comment: @1cm69, I have edited the answer, I think you should define a method that encapsulates your code to find the date data in the Bitmap and then simply call that method in your LINQ expression, as shown now in the answer. Note that I have not attempted to check the code extracting the date, that is taken from your code snippet.

Comment: thank you so much for this, is the method you posted supposed to completely replace my current `foreach`

Comment: You can remove that `foreach` loop, yes, you only need the XDocument construction code with the `from .. select ..` expression calling the method.

Comment: Thanks @martin still trying to get my head around your last comment about 'defining a method that encapsulates...', I have no idea what that means, it's a steep learning curve for me

Comment: If you are trying to write C# without knowing what a method is or where it belongs then take a step back and start with a tutorial or guide like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx.

Comment: thank you. I think I pretty much knew what a method is just not the terminology, only self taught and a little dabbling, it's the encapsulation I was scratching my head about. I'll get there eventually, lots of reading and searching to do.

Comment: @1cm69, now that the problem is solved you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XElements they are designed to work with Linq so try something like this:

```
var filePaths = GetFiles(@"C:\SomeDir");
var xml = new XElement("tr", 
    filePaths.Select(fp => new XElement("td", fp.FullName)));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I don't exactly know at what point in my code I need to insert this.

Comment: When placing it around the point of where I would like the new `<TR>` I get many, many errors that start with `var` not available in this context & it is asking for `)` after `)` & `;` all over the place but never seems to be happy.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack Overflow and forgot to add commenters name when replying, so: @mant101

Comment: I had a look at your code but you really need to break all the XML creation up into sub functions to make it readable. I would guess put `new XElement("tr", 
    filePaths.Select(fp => new XElement("td", fp)));` where you have `///  **** NEED TO INSERT LOOP HERE TO DYNAMICALLY CREATE NUMBER OF ELEMENTS DEPENDING ON NUMBER OF FILES IN DIRECTORY ****`. You may need to change the body of the Select to do whatever you need if the `td` needs attrbutes or whatever.